# Have arts.stackexchange.com redirect to Arts & Crafts

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks

A question on the Movies & TV meta site, '[film.stackexchange.com should redirect to the site](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4813/film-stackexchange-com-should-redirect-to-the-site)', reminded me of this:

Should we let `arts.stackexchange.com` redirect to our site? It currently leads to a 404.

Comment: Side note: for some reason posting the link doesn't automatically change it to its title.

Comment: There's a browser add-on called **Copy As Markdown**.  You right-click on the web page and it copies both the page title and the link in the form [Title](URL).  When you paste that, it displays the page title rather than the link.  What is in the square brackets is what is displayed.  You can edit that without affecting the link; what's captured by the extension sometimes has extraneous information.

Comment: Good idea.  You could also redirect art.stackexchange.com, which is a logical variation people might type.  If you really wanted to be sneaky, redirect anything that isn't already claimed so we get the traffic.  :-)  (Not serious about the last part.)

Comment: @fixer1234 It's just that on most sites - and I believe here as well - pasting links of threads into the body of either a question or an answer will automatically convert/display them to/as the question's title (and update whenever they're edited).

Comment: Stupid question, but what is the goal of this? In theory this is a great idea but I cannot remember the last time I typed any URL into anything. Is this really going to create more traffic?

Comment: @Elmy It's not so much that, but the consistency of it. Although I have a times checked to see if a dedicated SE site existed by using that format, so it might bring in a handful of users every year :) Another plus is that using direct links is a lot more energy-efficient than using a search engine (but that is not a serious concern either).

Comment: @Elmy, it probably wouldn't create substantive new traffic.  But if it's easy to do, why not?  Can't hurt.  It might help someone arrive less frustrated if they tried typing the URL with "arts" and then didn't have to double check and retype.  :-)  Anybody who lands here that way may have a more technical orientation (keyboard/CLI vs. GUI user)